# Mongo DB - find() in array of arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have such an data structure

```
{
    "level1": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "level2": [
                [
                    {
                        "id": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "id": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How i can get element with id 3 via find() operator?
`level2` always has two arrays

I tried this - `model.find({ 'level1.level2.$[i].$[j].id': 3 })`, but its not working

Comment: `'level1.level2.id': 3` assuming `level1` and `level2` are static and known field names

Comment: Oh when you say "get element", are you referring to removing all of the other array entries (eg with `$filter`)?

Comment: `level1.level2.id': 3` will not work if `level2` is an array of arrays. See [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fwuKcn6UZtr)

Comment: when you say "get element", i mean, thet i'll get find() request, and this request return me some object
for example: `variable = db.model.find(this should be filter, that return me object with id = 3 property)`
variable = { id: 3 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `level2` is an array of arrays, you can use:

```
db.collection.find({
  "level1.level2": {$elemMatch: {$elemMatch: {id: 3}}}
})
```

to find the relevant document.
See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XaG06sUcXGf)